# Reusable Ember Component across different modules

Tags: ember.js

I have two ember apps in the same website and I want to share common components.

In my app#1 (App1 namespace) I have this template which tries to make use of a drag-element component:

```
{{#drag-element item=item.id elementName='num' dragType='visits'}}
  test
{{/drag-element}}
```

I have defined the component in a different namespace like this:

`Common.DragElementComponent = Ember.Component.extend({...});`

How do I reference this component from App1 which is a different namespace than Common?

Comment: Have you tried `App1.DragElementComponent=Common.DragElementComponent` ?

Comment: Wonderful, that works. So, that's the standard approach?

Comment: Don't know about standard approach because I've never dealt with two apps on the same page. If you'd use Ember CLI you could probably get away with having one "vendor.js" and the `import` the same component in both apps..